# MongoDB/Mongoose: Updating entire document with findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use the `findOneAndUpdate()` method to either create a document if it doesn't exist, or update it if does exist. Consider the following code:

```
SampleComment = new Comment({
    id: '00000001',
    name: 'My Sample Comment',
    ...
})
```

This is my attempt to find out if `SampleComment` aldready exists, and if so, update it, otherwise creating it:

```
Comment.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: SampleComment.id }, 
    { SampleComment }, // <- NOT PASSING THE OBJECT
    { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, 
    function(error, result) {
        ...
});
```

I'm trying to pass the Model-instance as an object in the second argument, but result is only returning the default values of the model. Same goes for the document itself.

How do I pass the entire object `SampleComment` correctly in the second argument?

Answer (score 7):

What's actually happening when you're calling `findOneAndUpdate()` with your `Document` object as your update object with `{ SampleComment }` is you're destructuring that to be `SampleComment : {...}`.

Mongoose will then go and look at your database document for any property named `SampleComment`, find none, and then do nothing. Returning to you a document where nothing would have changed.

What you can do to fix this is convert your Document back to a plain update object first with Mongoose's `toObject()` method, remove the `_id` (since that property is immutable and you don't want to replace it anyway with an update) and then save it with your existing `findOneAndUpdate()` method. eg:

```
let newComment = SampleComment.toObject();
delete newComment._id;

Comment.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: SampleComment.id }, 
    newComment,
    { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, 
    function(error, result) {
        ...
    }
);
```

You can then see the updated document in your database. To receive the updated document in your `result` you need to also pass the option `{ new: true }` to your options object.

Here's the link to Mongoose's [toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toObject) Document method documentation.

Answer (score 1):

By default the returned result is going to be the unaltered document. If you want the new, updated document to be returned you have to pass an additional argument named `new` with the value `true`.

```
Comment.findOneAndUpdate({id: SampleComment.id}, SampleComment, {new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, function(error, result) {
    if(error){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(result);
});
```

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate:

```
function(error, doc) {
  // error: any errors that occurred
  // doc: the document before updates are applied if `new: false`, or after updates if `new = true`
}
```

Comment: I've tried the `{new: true}` parameter, but something else appears to be wrong. When adding `$set` i get: `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'toObject' of null]`

Comment: Try printing out the `SampleComment` in the console to see if it's not null. Also, I removed $set from my post, try putting `SampleComment` without curly brackets around it.

Comment: console.log returns the full object with all properties in place. I've tried removing $set and  the curly brackets. The error disappeared but the object still isn't passed on and the db document remains empty but for the default values.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. I send the object from a form ( with 22 fields) so it's not practical at all writting all the fields. The best would be like overwritting the document or similar. Did you find the way out @ComfortEagle ?

Comment: This actually doesn't fix the issue. When passing a Document as an update object the database is not updated and no errors are thrown either. Can confirm. @ComfortEagle did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make it easy and fast :D

In my case I Just needed to **insert the object from a form and update the doc.** Maybe that helps someone:

**Angularjs Controller:**

```
  $scope.bike ={};
  fBikeFactory.get({
        id:$stateParams.id
      })
      .$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.bike = response;
      },function (response) {
        $scope.bike = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
      });


// UPDATE a BIKE
      $scope.saveBike = function() {
        $scope.processing = true;

        var updateQuery = fBikeFactory.update({id: $stateParams.id}, $scope.bike);
        updateQuery.$promise.then(function(rep) {
            $scope.processing = false;
            $scope.message = "Desat amb èxit";
            setTimeout(function(){ $state.go('home.adminBikes');$scope.bike.message = ''; }, 750);
        },function(err) {
            $scope.processing = false;
            $scope.message = 'Error al Desar, torna a provar-ho.';
        })
      };
```

Require the model:

```
var Bike = require('../models/bikeModel.js');
```

...

**ROUTE:**

```
bikesRouter.route('/bikes/:id')
    .put(function(req,res) {


    Bike.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: req.params.id}, // find a document with that filter
            req.body, // document to insert 
            {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}, // options
            function (err, updatedBike) { // callback
                if (err) console.log('ERROR '+ err);
                else res.json(updatedBike)

            }
        );
    });
```

Hope that helps :D